# How to get mp4/mov/m4v video link for a youtube video?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, youtube

Can we get the file url for any video loaded on youtube? I am not happy using the youtube player in my application and would like to launch it using a instance of MPMoviePlayerController.

PS: Will be tagging it php also as developers across domains would also have had this sort of requirement

Comment: I think a lot of people would like to know that, but I'm afraid there is no such thing. Also, internally, the YouTube player might also be MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this ?

You could get the url of the video and implement it in another video controller.

http://www.ngcoders.com/php/php-youtube-video-downloader-script

You could use Curl to stream it back to your users.

Answer (score 1):

I do this within my iOS app by using https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

There is an LBYouTubeExtractor class that makes it easy to grab the iOS friendly file for any youtube link you pass to it.

```
LBYouTubeExtractor* extractor = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:URL quality:quality];
extractor.delegate = self;
[extractor startExtracting];
```

Works quite well....Good luck.